# how to wait for the complete execution of asynctask in using onbindviewholder?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    User user = mUsers.get(position);
    String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    new AddTodatabase4(user.email,currentuser).execute();
    System.out.println("checking check"+check);

    if(check==1){
        holder.status.setText("message");}

    String alphabet = user.email.substring(0, 1);

    holder.txtUsername.setText(user.email);
    holder.txtUserAlphabet.setText(alphabet);

  //  System.out.println(currentuser+" "+user.email);


}
```

Here, addtodatabase4 extends asynctask and check is a global variable. I wish to hold the rest of the execution of onbindviewholder until addtodatabase4 completes its execution as i need the modified value of check when setting my status textview using settext. How to achieve this. Using this code addtodatabse4 executes at the end .

Comment: Put the things you want to do after the task completes in the task's `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flag:

```
public static boolean isDownloadFinished = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        isDownloadFinished = false;
    }
```

Inside `onPostExecute` set isDownloadFinished to `true`.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
  super.onPreExecute();
   if (success) {
   isDownloadFinished = true;
  }else{
      isDownloadFinished = false;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
if(YourClass.isDownloadFinished){
    // do your task here
}
```

Comment: even asynctask.get not working...the onbindview function first sets the different views..

Comment: Where do you call `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`  ?

Comment: set your adapter inside `onPostExecute`.

Comment: i need to pass user.email each time to addtodatabse4 so cant set my adapater in postexecute.

Answer (score 0):

Well i passed the whole viewholder to the asynctask and then set my status textview there itself after checking the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing that `holder` to the asynctask like

```
new AddTodatabase4(user.email,currentuser, holder).execute();
```

and set the textViews in the holder in `onPostCreate` of the AsyncTask.